# How to get Tumblr post grid layout?

Tags: css, tumblr

I would like it so that there are two posts inline in `#postholder` in the following HTML:

```
<div id="postholder">
<div id="post">
{block:Posts}
{block:Photo}<a href="{Permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-400}" alt="PhotoAlt" class="photo"></a>{/block:Photo}
{block:Text}{block:Title}{Title}{/block:Title}{Body}{/block:Text}
{/block:Posts}
</div>
```

and this is the CSS for both `#post` and `#postholder`:

```
#postholder{
    border:dotted;
    width:807px;
    left:-400px;
    margin-left:60%;
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
}

#post{
    width:400px;
    float:left;
    width: 400px; 
    position: relative; 
    margin: 1%; 
}
```

Like this in a way:http://unrealisticness.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
{block:Posts}
<div id="post">
...
</div>
{/block:Posts}
```

This way, the "post" div renders for every post instead of wrapping all your posts in it.